# Fail to add the final line into .txt file - Android

Tags: java, android, java-io

The app continuously records down the sensor data and write them into a .txt file located in the SD card of the phone. Everything works nicely while writing in the data.

I have a stop button. Once the button is pressed, the recording will be ended and a final line is to be appended at the very end of the file.

But I always fail to append the final line.

I have debugged quite a long time. The code indeed runs the command that appends the last line first and then closes all the writers.

Do please help!

```
        // stop button
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // intend to append the final line
                myPrintWriter.flush();
                myPrintWriter.write("This is the final line");

                try {
                    myOutWriter.flush();
                    myOutWriter.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             try {
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole code can be simplified to below (with appropriate try catches). The rest is unnecessary.

```
// intend to append the final line
myPrintWriter.write("This is the final line");
myPrintWriter.flush();
myPrintWriter.close();
```

Calling close on the printwriter closes the underlying writer.

Comment: In fact, I even think the flush is redundant as close should call flush.

Comment: Could this solve my problem? Actually, I am confused by PrintWriter, BufferedWriter, FileWriter. I will appreciate it if you can help explain the difference.

Comment: FileWriter is an OutputStreamWriter which basically means its a bridge between writer (allow you to deal in strings and characterstreams) and an outputstream (deals in bytes). There is no buffering and writing to a file is an IO operation which can be expensive so you want to reduce the number of times you write to the file. A BufferedWriter does this as it can basically adds an in memory buffer to all write operations of the underlying writer and only writes to the underlying writer when the buffer is full or flush is called thereby reducing the number of write operations to the file.

Comment: A PrintWriter adds convenience methods for formatting the text including all the print** and format** style methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add following instead of your one,

```
 myPrintWriter.append("This is the final line");
 myPrintWriter.close();
```